# A novel way to kasher a traif oven

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Several years ago, a close friend, about to convert (not sure if it was herself, or me) asked me this:

If placing a traif (non-kosher steak) in a kosher oven makes the entire oven traif, then to make my traif oven kosher, why can't I just cook a kosher steak in it?

BTW, I mentioned "steak" as an example. But, I know that my friend meant any type of kosher food placed in a traif oven.

I have no answer to this question. Perhaps, you can answer?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: I cannot immediately think of a higher-steak question.

Comment: @CodeswithHammer funny. See latest edits, though.

Comment: After reading the edit, I see the question is more general than I thought.  I recommend potential answers consider [the discourse of Hazzan Hadash](http://yakov.bandcamp.com/track/eatin-kosher-chicken).

Comment: @Nᴮᶻ: Thanks, I had a random space before the close bracket on my most recent attempt.  Not it works.

Comment: A real novel way would be to put a book in the oven ;)

Comment: @andrewmh20: Cooking the books requires heating the oven to 451 degrees F, until the writing on the pages glows.

Comment: The Law of Sewage: A drop of wine in a barrel of sewage makes sewage; a drop of sewage in a barrel of wine makes sewage.

Comment: @ColBeseder Hmmph! You're comparing a traif oven to sewage?